# Android List with Sections like in example from developer.android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to implement a List with Sections in my android app. I found an example screenshot on this link: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html

But there is no downloadable example, so that I can have a look how to implement this.

Where can I find an example, how to make an List with Sections?

Comment: have you tried expandable list views?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet... is there no standard like iOS has?

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the website you will see the button "Developer Docs" there you will find [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) site. It only teaches you how to create a Listview, but you could achieve this sections by adding a horizontal line to divide each section.

Comment: I found this site, but I'm confused that Android has no standards like iOS has?

Comment: In iOS you have a List-Component "TableView" and can switch between Grouped, Sectionend and Plain Style with one click. That is on all devices the exact the same look and feel. I don't saw this for Android. Why? On standard apps like Contacts, there is such an List with sections.